# How can I test the actual resolution of my camera when I acquire a frame using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera

I am working in Python/OpenCV, acquiring frames from a USB webcam (Logitech C615 Camera, supposedly HD 1080p).  1080p has a 16:9 aspect ratio and thus I should be able to acquire images at all of these resolutions:

```
1920 x 1080
1600 x 900
1366 x 768
1280 x 720
1024 x 576
```

I didn't write the camera driver however, so how do I know if I am really getting these pixels off of the camera?  For example, I can specify 3840 x 2160 and I get a video frame of that size!

Is there a systematic way I can evaluate/determine the real resolution or effective resolution of the camera given these different resolution settings?  Below is some Python/OpenCV code to demonstrate.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, cv
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # note you may need to pass 1 instead of 0 into this to get your camera  

cap.set(3,3840)     #horizontal pixels
cap.set(4,2160)     #vertical pixels
cap.set(5, 15)      #frame rate
time.sleep(2)       #trying to solve a delay issue ... never mind this


#acquire the video from the camera
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("captured video", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
w = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
h = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
print(w, h)
while cam.isOpened():
    err, img = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("lalala", img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH'

Comment: oh, my bad, (3.0 here) try cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH

Comment: thanks!  apparently the constants are missing.  http://code.opencv.org/issues/3181    it's cam.get(3) and cam.get(4).  i am apparently getting 1080p from the camera.

Comment: please, no. opencv 3.0 is just around the corner, like 30 more days to go. there won't be any CV_* constants, or cv2.cv ones around. let's keep it as it is

Comment: thanks, didn't know that.  will be sure to upgrade next month.

Comment: I think it's actually cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH

Comment: A bit too late, but its actually ```cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH``` for OpenCV 3.x